# Error in rviz while using hector mapping and RPLidar

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need some help solving the following error in rviz:  No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist. I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. Below is my mapping_default.launch code:

-->
    
  
    
  -->

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266947/error-in-rviz-while-using-hector-mapping-and-rplidar/) by [ebaker8664](https://answers.ros.org/users/31289/ebaker8664/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you're not actually broadcasting a map transform in this launch file. The map_frame param isn't used in this config and you need someone to publish this transform into your map.

You can get around this to view your data by setting the global frame in RVIZ to a frame that exists in the robot transforms assuming your URDF is made correctly, if not, using the laser scanner base link.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0